# In Unity3D's Web Player I can't access an XML file

Tags: xml, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I have made a game with Unity3D that has to access an XML file. I have put the file in the Assets folder and when I debug the game in Unity it works properly. The problem is that when I build the game and launch it in the browser (web player) it doesn't work. It gives the following error:

MethodAccessException: Attempt to access a private/protected method failed

Does it have to do with the security restrictions of the web player?

Comment: A file being in the Assets folder does not imply it gets included in your build. Did you mean to put it in your Resources? And can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: In fact I've also tried to put the xml file in the same folder as the executable files, but it doesn't work. As for the code I've used the classes  included in System.XML (XMLDocument, XMLNode, XMLNodeList, ...)

Comment: How are you accessing the file's contents? WebPlayer tends to restrict access to the file system, which could pose a problem. I've also heard of some rare errors when reflection calls try to access protected constructors.

Comment: Try adding the XML file in the Resources folder, and loading it through Resources.Load. Unity includes everything in the Resources folder into your build. Since it's "within" the build, the security sandbox won't throw errors when trying to load the file

Comment: @Venkat you should provide this as an answer because it is the right way to load external resources in Unity and probably will work even in webplayer.

Comment: @Frohlich, yeah should probably do that. No idea why I stuck it in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as an answer here

1. Move the XML file into the **Resources** folder.
2. Use [Resources.Load](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) to load the file as a [TextAsset](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html)
3. Grab the text using TextAsset.text

Quick Example

```
public class LoadAnXML : Monobehaviour {

    void Start () {
        var xmlText = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("MyXML").text;
        //Do stuff with the text here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Venkat is right, it's necessary to use Resources.Load. But In my case, as I use C#, the code which works best is this:

```
XmlDocument xmldocument = new XmlDocument ();
xmldocument.LoadXml (Resources.Load<TextAsset> ("my_xml_file").text);
```